# lua - limit characters of inputted text - love2d

Tags: input, lua, character, limit, love2d

I have a function that allows me to add and remove character in a line by i want to limit it to around 10 characters

```
function love.keypressed(key, unicode)
    if key == "backspace" or key == "delete" then
        player = string.sub(player, 1, #player-1)
    elseif unicode > 31 and unicode < 127 then
        player = player .. string.char(unicode)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just restrict the length by not adding to the string if it's too long?
Or were you after something else?

```
function love.keypressed(key, unicode)
    if key == "backspace" or key == "delete" then
        player = string.sub(player, 1, #player-1)
    elseif unicode > 31 and unicode < 127 and #player <=10 then
        player = player .. string.char(unicode)
    end
end
```

Comment: `player = string.sub(player, 1, #player-1)` could be replaced with `player = player:sub(1,-2)`